# How to port delphi library to Win CE?

Tags: delphi, windows-mobile

I have a win32 library (DLL) project that was originally written in Delphi. It was used in various application and is working fine.

Now I need to use same functionality in Win CE applications. I understand that same DLL cannot be directly used. What are my options to port the code to Win CE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not much you can do really, Delphi does not support Windows CE.

You might try porting to [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/). That supports a host of OS's including WinCE and a host of platforms including ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe converting it Delphi for dotNET (nowadays called Delphi Prism) could work. I have no experience with this, though.

Comment: Prism was updated with CF support somewhere after D2009. Don't know how practical it is. However I don't think recoding it in Prism is significantly easier than recoding it directly in C#

Comment: @Marco: That depends on the library. If it compiles with Prism without many changes, it would be much easier than recoding in C#.

Comment: Prism is a different dialect.

Comment: @Marco: But according to marketing (I have no personal experience with it) it is very compatible to Delphi. If it was me who was tasked with porting that library I would try Prism first.

Comment: Then that marketing is nonsense. Are you sure you are not mixing up Delphi.NET? E.g. the fact that Prism has "method" instead of procedure means a compatibility problem in about every other line. This is clearly visible in the examples on their site and in wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

I think FreePascal/Lararus will do the job quite well and you still get to use most of your nonvisual code from delphi